# Can we improve appeal to new users by rewarding question improvements (response to mod flags)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, new-users, gamification

I see many discussions, on Meta and offsite, where new users rebuke the mod feedback that occurs in modded questions (unclear, low quality, dupe, etc).

The modding is completely appropriate, but it also create a community that more closed-off to newbies.  I think that *threshold begets quality*, but this is a proposal for how we can do better.

> New users adjusting to question-asking style, I propose, has become
>   its own scale of advancement that is worthy of reputation points.

What is this rubbish?  Newbie users have little rep already, and in language tags with high answer saturation, there is low likelihood of asking a meaningful new question (or answer).  But the improvements they make in asking questions is, itself, **real advancement** in this community.  When they're mod-flagged, and then make good changes, the flags can/should come off.

**Rep for learning commonly-failed conventions**

Giving rep points for these changes would gamify their process of learning proper Q&A style.  It would keep them learning by rewarding good behavior.  If you consider it now, most newbies that face the mod-flag challenges have a *huge* cliff to climb, and no reward is given to them, other than 1 or 2 people finally answering their clarified question.  Rarely does their question get many votes (since it's such a newbie question), which translates into few rep points in exchange for all their effort.

**Limits**

These rep points would only be available to new and low-rep users, and there would be a natural limit on them as the user exceeded the threshold points that defined them as "low rep."  Perhaps a 50 point rep limit before these rewards are not available.

Knowledge is its own reward, but a more gradated rewards curve is suitable for the meta-learning process of being a new user asking flag-worth questions.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking or proposing. Users already are rewarded for improving questions by the upvotes they get for it, and the fact that the questions can become reopened upon review. What more are you suggesting? Also, by "mod flags" do you mean close votes?

Comment: I think this proposal would benefit greatly from being more specific about what sort of schedule of rewards you're thinking of, perhaps as a self-answer?

Comment: @NathanTuggy ok, sounds right.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... I get what you're shooting for here, but the reward for asking a well formed question is usually a well formed answer. Reputation points can be a nice side benefit, but rep shouldn't be the primary goal when asking a question.

> translates into few rep points in exchange for all their effort

There really isn't that much effort required when asking a question.

- Has it been asked before?
- Is it at least somewhat legible?
- Is it on-topic for the site?

That's really not asking for a whole lot is it?

Also further gamification tends to lead people to game the system. How would your proposed rep system tell the difference between users who are honestly struggling to understand the system and users who would, *and believe me they would*, deliberately ask poorly formed questions just to go back and correct them for the points?

Comment: "That's really not asking for a whole lot is it?" and yet brash green users still fail this.  Maybe 'we don't want their kind here' but I'm saying we can be more inclusive and nurturing to this facet of inexperience

Comment: @NewAlexandria We already take the time to answer and, more often than not, edit their questions and we offer an awful lot of resources to teach new users to use the site. When I started on SO, getting someone to help me with my problem was more than enough incentive for me to learn the ropes.